# Can I register a car with Nevada plates to my Sentri Account if I currently live in Arizona and the car is not mine?

Tags: sentri

I was given a car by an aunt and the car still has Nevada plates for a year, I do not plan on changing the registration to arizona until the plates expire, is it possible to still add that car to my Sentri account so I can cross the border?

Comment: To add further info for the linked duplicate Q&A (I was asker and answerer on that question), I registered for Sentri in California (I live in Mexico) and the car has South Dakota plates

Comment: Do you now have the car title? If so one state (yours or your aunt’s) may have an issue with that. But that isn’t a Travel issue…